# A lot of time to reboot after creatre a RAID1

Tags: linux, hard-drive, debian, raid-1

I created a RAID1. All looks working fine, but it is taking nearly two minutes to shut down or reboot the server.

No idea where to start looking for the problem.

This is the configuration:

```
NAME           SIZE FSTYPE            TYPE  MOUNTPOINT
sda            1.8T                   disk  
└─sda1           1T linux_raid_member part  
  └─md0     1023.9G ext4              raid1 
sdb            1.8T                   disk  
└─sdb1           1T linux_raid_member part  
  └─md0     1023.9G ext4              raid1 
sdc          931.5G                   disk  
nvme0n1      465.8G                   disk  
├─nvme0n1p1    512M vfat              part  /boot/efi
├─nvme0n1p2  464.3G ext4              part  /
└─nvme0n1p3    976M swap              part  [SWAP]
```

Comment: The question is if after these 2 minutes if the performance is correct.

Comment: I would say yes. At least, I did not find any issue. So this is normal?

Comment: I don't know about "normal", but I have seen other computers with 2 minutes boot.